# Overlay panel to Maps V3

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

In google Maps V3, I need to overlay a panel instead of Marker. I did this in V2 by just using addControlWidget() method. Here is the code along with css. Please help me in implementing the same in V3.

```
ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
     FlexTable fTable = new FlexTable();
     fTable.setWidget(0, 1, new HTML("TEST1"));
     fTable.setWidget(1, 1, new HTML("TEST2"));
     panel.add(fTable);
     panel.setStyleName("cssstyle");
     MapWidget map = new MapWidget();
      map.addControlWidget(panel);
```

CSS Code :

```
.cssstyle {
         z-index: 1;
         float: right;
         position: absolute;}
```

Trying to overlay custom widget or panel at the top of map (i.e, like showing legends in charts)..

Comment: take a look at [CustomControls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls)

Comment: Thanks... Got output... Will post GWT Code Soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CustomControls I can able to add (overlay) a panel in GWT Maps V3. [Here](http://ameenit.blogspot.in/2013/02/overlay-panel-to-maps-v3.html) is the code...